# How to Authenticate to Anchor.fm form using Python?

Tags: python, html, authentication

I'm trying to use Python to authenticate to https://anchor.fm/login.

The problem is that the payload requires a `_csrf` property.
So I don't think it's possible to use a simple POST method.

So, I would like to know if it is possible to get the attributes of the form (`id="LoginForm"`) to do the authentication:

[image: HTML Login Form]

If yes, is there any package that helps me to do this? Or some other method.

Comment: See [ask]. There's no such property named by '_csrf' in the form element. That page seems to do an AJAX request to get the token. Anyway, I recommend to use an automation framework, such as Selenium.

Comment: Any problem with my question? Let me know and I would be fine editing it.

Comment: You said 'to get the attributes of the form...  to do the authentication', implying there exists a property named '_csrf' in the form element. But's it not true.(You can see that from the DOM browser of the browser.) You are better to give more detail on the '_csrf' symbol, e.g., a sample of the HTTP request body.

Comment: Excuse me, I thought it would be implied. I forget that some people need precise explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login page makes a GET request to `https://anchor.fm/api/csrf` to get a csrf token. This request also sets a cookie, which is then sent together with the login form. I haven't checked that, but it seems it should be enough to make that GET request, grab the csrf token and the cookie, and attach them to the POST you make with the login form. (the csrf token in the `_csrf` body field, as you noted)

Comment: It helped me a lot. But my request only returns *Forbidden*. In Insomnia and other REST tools, it is working. I am using: `requests.post('https://anchor.fm/api/login', json=data)`. I am sure data is correct.

Comment: Are you sending the cookies?

Comment: I am using `session.get('https://anchor.fm')` but print session.cookies is empty.

Comment: I think the session bag is meant for your own session cookies, not the ones that you get from backend requests to external sources (where do you get that `session` variable from?). What you would have to do is: 1. make a GET request to the csrf endpoint. Grab the response. 2. From the response take the `Set-Cookie` header and get the value for the `anchorpw_s` cookie. 3. When you make a POST request to /login, add a `Cookie` header to the request with the `anchorpw_s` cookie and its value. I think you have to do it "manually".